# Как поменять позицию блока WordPress + WooCommerce + WoodMart?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем здоровья!

Сайт на Вордпресс, тема WoodMart.
Подскажите пожалуйста как поменять позицию блока "Индикатор бесплатной доставки" в карточке товара?
**Сейчас это выглядит вот так:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**А надо, что бы было так:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В файле темы нашел такой код

```
/**
   * Output shipping progress bar.
   */
  public function output_shipping_progress_bar() {
    if ( ! woodmart_get_opt( 'shipping_progress_bar_enabled' ) ) {
      return;
    }

    if ( woodmart_get_opt( 'shipping_progress_bar_location_card_page' ) && ! Builder::get_instance()->has_custom_layout( 'cart' ) ) {
      add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table', array( $this, 'render_shipping_progress_bar_with_wrapper' ) );
    }

    if ( woodmart_get_opt( 'shipping_progress_bar_location_single_product' ) ) {
      add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'render_shipping_progress_bar_with_wrapper' ), 29 );
    }

    if ( woodmart_get_opt( 'shipping_progress_bar_location_checkout' ) ) {
      add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing', array( $this, 'render_shipping_progress_bar_with_wrapper' ) );
    }
  }
```

Как мне правильно прописать в файле functions.php, что бы изменить позицию эту

```
if ( woodmart_get_opt( 'shipping_progress_bar_location_single_product' ) ) {
      add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'render_shipping_progress_bar_with_wrapper' ), 29 );
    }
```

На эту

```
if ( woodmart_get_opt( 'shipping_progress_bar_location_single_product' ) ) {
      add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'render_shipping_progress_bar_with_wrapper' ), 30 );
    }
```